# Trying to add an element to an cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have trying to find a code that will look at the contents of a cell `G1` and then search column A for a match and select that cell.

This is part of a longer code, but this is the only bit I can't find out how to do.

Comment: Edit your post and add some code to show us what you've done so far

Comment: Sorry SO is not a code writing service. Please consider doing a research first and then posting your questions/issues together with your findings.

Comment: Hint. Record a macro with the operations you want and look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub searchnFind()
Dim searchResult As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

Set searchResult = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:=ws.Range("G1").Value, _
    LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False)

If Not searchResult Is Nothing Then
searchResult.Select
End If

End Sub
```